# Creating a file and write to it random chars using System Calls operations

Tags: c, operating-system, system-calls

I'm trying to create a file and copy to it a random chars of 256 MB sizes all by System Calls operations and I just can't understand how should I do that.

Obviously I need the file to be txt file so when I tried to use the **creat** function with O_RDWR flag but it didn't creat a txt file, it was something unknown which I couldn't open. I saw a PERMS thing on web, which I didn't understand. This is what I wrote so far:

```
char buff[1024*1024]; 
j=0;
for (i=0;i<(1024*1024);i++){
    if (j==256) j=0;

    buff[i]='a'+j;

    j++;
}

fd= open(argv[1], O_RDWR);
if (fd < 0) { 
    fd= creat(argv[1],O_RDWR);
    for (i=0; i<256; i++) {
        write(fd, buff, 1024*1024);
    }
```

It does create the file, but it is inaccessible and it is of size 0.

Comment: Well, a file that contains all 256 possible patterns of an 8-bit byte is not going to look much like a text file, as the values 0-31 and >= 128 (assuming ASCII) aren't really text-ish...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second argument of `creat()` is not the same as of `open()`.

The constant `O_RDWR` is defined as 2 and is misinterpreted as the file mode bits, which means you can't read the file.

Comment: I fixed it to "S_IRWXU" as I was suggested by the 'man' command, but still the file is empty..

Answer (score 0):

Check your program logic. `if (fd < 0)` is false and `write()` is never executed.